# How can I use action text on active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

i'm using rails 6.0.0 and ruby 2.6.0, I want to know what's the best way to use ActionText in ActiveAdmin, should I have to use render?

Answer (score 3):

I used this `f.rich_text_area :content` inside ActiveAdmin but it didn't work for me so I added `<trix-editor>` tag inside a custom form following this [Form Partial Tricks](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Form-Partial-Tricks)
 but also this didn't work so I ended up using this gem [ActiveAdmin Quill Editor](https://github.com/blocknotes/activeadmin_quill_editor) it was easy to setup and worked perfectly

### Install

- Add this to your Gemfile `gem 'activeadmin_quill_editor'`
- in your `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss` file, add this:

```
@import 'activeadmin/quill_editor_input';
```

- in your `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js` file, add this:

```
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor/quill
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor_input
```

### Example

```
# ActiveAdmin article form conf:
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Article' do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description, as: :quill_editor
      f.input :published
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to include the css/js assets via webpacker, so including them through es6 imports?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin_quill_editor'
```

in your app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss

```
@import 'activeadmin/quill_editor/quill.snow';
@import 'activeadmin/quill_editor_input';
```

in your app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js

```
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor/quill
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor_input
```

app/admin/posts.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :title, :text, :tag_list
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Article' do
      f.input :tag_list, :input_html => {:value => f.object.tag_list.join(", ") }, :label => "Tags (separated by commas)".html_safe
      f.input :title
      f.input :text, as: :quill_editor, input_html: { data:
        { options:
          { modules:
            { toolbar:
              [%w[bold italic underline strike],
               %w[blockquote code-block],
               [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
               [{ 'align': [] }],
               ['link'],
               [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
               [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
               [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
               [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],
               [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
               [{ 'font': [] }],
               ['clean'],
               ['image'],
               ['video']] },
            theme: 'snow' } } }
      # f.input :published
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

[It works](https://github.com/cmirnow/CRUD-Blog/blob/master/app/admin/posts.rb).